# How to switch between the upper and lower pane in emacs?

Tags: emacs, erlang

I am using the erlang mode in Aquamacs.

The mode, by default, creates a new pane and buffer "*erlang*" when I hit C-C C-K to compile an erlang file. (as seen in the attached screen shot)

What is the easiest way to switch between these two panes?

I do not think "C-x b" is applicable in this case because 'C-X b' then "*erlang" is slow considering I have to switch between my files and the erlang shell rather frequently.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly (I'm used to Emacs, but not aquamacs), your "panes" are called "windows" in standard Emacs terminology.

With standard key bindings, you can use `C-x o` (binded to `other-window`) to switch between windows.

There are also plenty of extensions allowing to manage windows. One of them is [`windmove`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove), which allows switching between windows using `S-<arrows>` key bindings.

Comment: Thanks! I am really not familiar with emacs terminology. 'Frame' in emacs is probably what I'd call a window, and a 'window' is what I'd call a pane.